# Is it possible to limit the scope of function apropos-value?

Tags: search

I've recently started using function `apropos-value` and have found its output burdensome-ly long, mainly due to a limited number of huge variables that I knew in advance would contain the value I was looking for, but which were not of interest to me.

Is there any way to limit the scope of function `apropos-value`, so that it not search certain variables?

In my case, I know in advance that the value will appear in variables such as `kill-ring`, `values`, `minibuffer-history`, and I have learned the hard way that taking a "hacktivist shortcut" such as `(setq kill-ring nil)` messes up future ability to use the kill ring.

Comment: You could try creating an interactive version of the command that lets you first select a subset of the variables using helm it another incremental completion framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to modify the function `apropos-value-internal`, which is used by `apropos-value`. For example,

```el
(define-advice apropos-value-internal
    (:around (old-fun predicate symbol function) ignore)
  "Ignore some variables for `apropos-value'."
  (unless (memq symbol '(kill-ring values minibuffer-history))
    (funcall old-fun predicate symbol function)))
```

However, if you think such feature might be also userful for others, you should consider reporting a bug (feature request) via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I tried your approach, and while it would work for a simple change to `apropos-value`, I couldn't get it to work for the kind of change I envisioned. See my answer for what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED 2018-04-07: "circular structure" issue resolved (explained in paragraph 4).

UPDATED 2018-04-07: A bug with `obarray` usage was fixed. See paragraph 7.

1. Below is a replacement for the stock emacs `apropos-value` function that I think will meet my needs.
2. User xuchunyang's answer would work for a basic change to `apropos-value`, and I did experiment with it, but it didn't seem like the correct tool for dealing with how I wanted universal prefix arguments to control how the function would operate.
3. User Drew's answer looks like it would work, but I was intimidated from even trying it because it seems overwhelming. Thanks Drew for pointing out the `icicles` package - I intend to give it a "test drive" at some point, but not for a simple operation such as this.
4. The code below had originally for me generated an error "Apparently circular structure being printed" (possibly because of [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-11/msg00242.html)). This was eventually resolved when restarting emacs! The error message may have been issued due to some memory management detail, because what caused me to restart emacs was a "memory exhausted" warning stubbornly ignored...
5. As of now (2018-04-08), the code works. Please let me know if you experience a problem with it. My intent is to add another feature to it, and to propose it as a patch to the emacs developers. The additional feature that I have in mind is a boolean variable `apropos-value-limited-print` to print only symbol names, not their content, in order to greatly reduce the size of the output buffer ( A user can always interrogate values with `C-h v` when point is on the symbol name).
6. I'll wait a few days for feedback before marking this (my own) answer as accepted.
7. I found and fixed a bug in how I was trying to create an `obarray`: "[Unlike Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp does not provide for interning a single symbol in several obarrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html)"

   ```
   (defcustom apropos-value-exclude-list
     '(kill-ring values minibuffer-history buffer-name-history
        command-history ivy--all-candidates)
   "List of variable names to be excluded from `apropos-value' searches" 
     :type '(repeat variable))


   (defun my-apropos-value (pattern &optional do-all)
     "Allow `apropos-value' to limit scope of its searches.

   With \\[universal-argument] prefix, or if `apropos-do-all' is
   non-nil, also looks at function definitions (arguments,
   documentation and body) and at the names and values of
   properties.

   With two \\[universal-argument] prefixes, excludes the variables
   listed in `apropos-value-exclude-list' from its search.

   With three \\[universal-argument] prefixes, performs a search
   only on the variables listed in `apropos-value-exclude-list'."
     (interactive (list (apropos-read-pattern "value")
                current-prefix-arg))
     (apropos-parse-pattern pattern)
     (or do-all (when apropos-do-all (setq do-all '(4))))
     (setq apropos-accumulator ())
     (let (f v p)
       (if (equal do-all '(64)) ; C-u C-u C-u
         (dolist (symbol apropos-value-exclude-list)
           (when (setq v (apropos-value-internal 'boundp symbol 'symbol-value))
             (setq apropos-accumulator
               (cons (list symbol (apropos-score-str v) nil v nil) apropos-accumulator))))
        (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
          (setq f nil v nil p nil)
          (or (memq symbol '(apropos-regexp
                  apropos-pattern apropos-all-words-regexp
                  apropos-words apropos-all-words
                  do-all apropos-accumulator apropos-value-exclude-list
                  symbol f v p))
              (and (equal do-all '(16)) ; C-u C-u
                   (memq symbol apropos-value-exclude-list))
              (setq v (apropos-value-internal 'boundp symbol 'symbol-value)))
          (when (equal do-all '(4)) ; C-u
            (setq f (apropos-value-internal 'fboundp symbol 'symbol-function)
                  p (apropos-format-plist symbol "\n    " t)))
          (if (apropos-false-hit-str v)
              (setq v nil))
          (if (apropos-false-hit-str f)
              (setq f nil))
          (if (apropos-false-hit-str p)
              (setq p nil))
          (if (or f v p)
              (setq apropos-accumulator (cons (list symbol
                             (+ (apropos-score-str f)
                                (apropos-score-str v)
                                (apropos-score-str p))
                             f v p)
                           apropos-accumulator)))))))
     (let ((apropos-multi-type (if (equal do-all '(4)) t nil)))
       (apropos-print nil "\n----------------\n")))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you use use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use [multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) **`icicle-apropos-value`**.

With a prefix arg you can limit the effect to only variables, functions, faces, plists, etc.

You can match not only the value but also the function/variable etc. name, if you wish ([multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions)).  So you can easily *exclude certain variables* (by name) from consideration.

More importantly, you can refine matches incrementally using [progressive completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion). And that includes being able to exclude matches ([chip away the non-elephant](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway)).

> **`icicle-apropos-value`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd1.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar help-menu apropos icicles
>   icicle-apropos-value`, `menu-bar help-menu apropos apropos-var-value`,
>   `menu-bar help-menu search-documentation find-option-by-value`.
>
> `(icicle-apropos-value)`
>
> Choose a variable, function, or other symbol description.
>   This is similar to vanilla command `apropos-value`, but you can match
>   against the variable *name* and its printed *value* at the same time.
>
> By default, each completion candidate is a [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) composed of
>   a variable name plus its value.  They are separated by
>   `icicle-list-join-string` (`"^G^J"`, by default).
>
> With a **prefix arg**, candidates are different kinds of symbols:
>
> - < 0: **functions** and their defs (but byte-compiled defs are skipped)
> - > 0: symbols and their **plists**
> - = 0: **variables** and their values, **functions** and their definitions, and
>      other symbols and their **plists**
> - plain (`C-u`): use the last-computed (cached) set of candidates
>
> You can use **`C-$`** during completion to toggle filtering the domain of
>   initial candidates according to the prefix argument, as follows:
>
> - none: only user **options** (+ values)
> - < 0: only **commands** (+ definitions)
> - > 0: only **faces** (+ plists)
> - = 0: only **options** (+ values), **commands** (+ defs), **faces** (+ plists)
>
> *See also:*
>
> - `icicle-apropos-vars-w-val-satisfying`,
>     `icicle-describe-vars-w-val-satisfying` - values satisfy a predicate
> - `icicle-plist` - similar to this command with positive prefix arg
> - `icicle-vardoc`, `icicle-fundoc`, `icicle-doc` - match name & doc
> - `icicle-apropos-options-of-type`, `icicle-describe-option-of-type` -
>     match name & defcustom type
>
> Because you will often use this command in contexts that result in
>   many, many completion candidates, the following are turned off by
>   default for this command:
>
> - Icomplete mode.  You can toggle this using **`M-i M-#`**.
> - Icicles incremental completion.  You can cycle this using **`M-i #`**.
>
> Read input, then call `icicle-doc-action`
>   to act on it.
>
> Input-candidate completion and cycling are available.  While cycling,
>   these keys with prefix `C-` are active:
>
> - `C-mouse-2`, `C-return` - Act on current completion candidate only
> - `C-down`, `C-wheel-down` - Move to next completion candidate and act
> - `C-up`, `C-wheel-up` - Move to previous completion candidate and act
> - `C-next`  - Move to next apropos-completion candidate and act
> - `C-prior` - Move to previous apropos-completion candidate and act
> - `C-end`   - Move to next prefix-completion candidate and act
> - `C-home`  - Move to previous prefix-completion candidate and act
> - `C-!`     - Act on *all* candidates, successively (careful!)
>
> When candidate action and cycling are combined (e.g. `C-next`), user
>   option **`icicle-act-before-cycle-flag`** determines which occurs first.
>
> With prefix **`C-M-`** instead of `C-`, the same keys (`C-M-mouse-2`,
>   `C-M-RET`, `C-M-down`, and so on) provide *help about candidates*.
>
> Use `mouse-2`, `RET`, or `S-RET` to finally choose a candidate, or
>   `C-g` to quit.
>
> This is an Icicles command - see command `icicle-mode`.

Comment: I up-voted this answer because it points out what seems to be an excellent package for emacs, but it also seems overwhelming for a solution to a single problem, and I was intimidated from trying it. I do intend at some point to give `icicles` a "test drive".